# Mongodb Nodejs Aggregration query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the below code for a aggregate query. However, I am unable to parse the result. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
MongoClient.connect(
                'mongodb://192.168.1.136:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false',
                { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
                function(connectErr, client) {
                  assert.equal(null, connectErr);
                  const coll = client.db('kaa').collection('logs_96775772132708234336');
                  coll.aggregate(agg, (cmdErr, result) => {
                    if (cmdErr) throw err;
                      console.log(result);
                      client.close();
                  });
                  
            });
```

Thanks And Regards,

Rupak Banerjee.

Comment: can you provide more deteails about the error and the query you try to make

Comment: You should add your full code. The `agg` object is missing in your code. Also add the error that you are getting in the question. Add which version of MongoDB and Mongoose are you using?

Comment: I am not facing any error. But unable to process the result.